# PHP Support Chat System

Tags: php, mysql, chat, live

I need a live chat system to support my clients and would like to write it using PHP and a MySQL, but I am not sure how to do this. Is it even possible in PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement Live chat on my site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302271/how-to-implement-live-chat-on-my-site)

Comment: You'll need javascript on the client side if you want it to be live/real-time.

Comment: Does it need to be built from scratch? There are existing PHP chat servers you can install. Just google PHP chat. There are also some tutorials out there: http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorials/PHP/Chat-Systems/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. 
[PHPOpenChat](http://www.phpopenchat.org/)

If you go through the source code for that you will get a good idea on how to create your own.

Comment: or you can just use that on your site. Why take all the pain and write something new? ;)

Answer (score 1):

These links may be helpful:

- http://www.meebo.com/
- http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorials/PHP/Chat-Systems/1

EmmyS provided the links; I found them very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. You will need of Javascript/Ajax tool (It's more simple if you use jquery for ajax), php and mysql. Basically everything stands in the Ajax tool that allows you to send http request to the server without refreshing the page.

Here's some usefull links:

[Jquery](http://jquery.com/)

[Ajax tut](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp)

Comment: The Mootools Library is very usefull too (also good Ajax functionality)

Answer (score 1):

There is also Rhino Live Support / Chat a free option is available.

https://www.livesupportrhino.com

Answer (score 0):

We also have a similar requirement - the client would like to have a live chat window on webpages to help visitors. They are *not* interested in related functionality like support desk etc.

Instead of implementing ourselves, we are liking the paid option of http://www.phplivesupport.com/

Around Dec 2013, they have two options:

- Hosted at their server solution at $ 10 per month. *Pros:* Easier to implement, cheaper initially. *Cons:* Data stored at third-party server, no access to source code for modification.
- Downloading (full source code) and installing on own server at $ 150 one-time. *Pros:* You own the software, can modify at will. *Cons:* Implementation required, (initially) expensive